# Clarifying the local linearity definition of derivative for $R^m$ to $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is from Munkres' Analysis on Manifold and I am already confused by multiple things already:

[image]

1. I understand the reason why we are dividing by the norm of h instead of h because a vector in  $R^m$ cannot divide a vector in $R^n$. But the part that makes me a bit uncomfortable is the fact that we lose "direction" if we only divide by the norm. In single-variable real analysis, we can show that |x| is not differentiable at 0 by showing that the left and right-hand limits do not agree, but how do we use this definition to show that |x| is not differentiable at 0?

2)I do not understand the proof that matrix B is unique. So the author assumed there was another matrix C and subtracted the two difference quotient and got (C-B)h/|h| approaches 0. After this, I'm not sure what the next step was. Why did he set  h=tu?

3. For example 2 given, I also don't understand this proof. I plugged Bx+h into the definition above and got $(Ba+Bh-Ba-Bh)/|h|$ approaches 0 as h approaches 0, but why does f(a+h)-f(a)=Bh imply that B is the derivative?

I apologize if this was too lengthy. This is my first time and everything feels super confusing compared to single-variable analysis.

Answer (score 1):

1. The function $x\mapsto|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$ because, if it was, then there would be a $1\times n$ matrix $B$ such that$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|h|-B.h}{|h|}=0,$$which is equivalent to$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{B.h}{|h|}=1.$$In particular, if $u=(1,0,\ldots,0)$,$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{B.(tu)}{|tu|}=1;$$in other words,$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac t{|t|}B.u=|u|=1.$$But $\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac t{|t|}B.u=B.u$ and $\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac t{|t|}B.u=-B.u$; you cannot have both $B.u$ and $-B.u$ equal to $1$.
2. He set $h=tu$ to complete the proof, just as I did above.
3. Because, by definition, $B$ is the derivative if$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B.h}{|h|}=0.\tag1$$So, since, in that case, that you mentioned, $(1)$ holds, then $B$ is the derivative.